# creating excel with POI java but date cell showing as hash(#) but it have value also

Tags: java, apache-poi

I'm setting cell style also as date formate but getting values as like below. and below is my code

```
if("java.util.Date".equals(obj.getClass().getName())) {
                            CellStyle cellStyle = workbook.createCellStyle();
                            CreationHelper createHelper = workbook.getCreationHelper();
                            cellStyle.setDataFormat(
                                createHelper.createDataFormat().getFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy"));
                            cell.setCellStyle(cellStyle);
                            cell.setCellValue(new Date());
                        } else
                            cell.setCellValue((String) obj);
```

[image]

How to fix this, please help me

Comment: This is simplest `Excel` basic knowledge. The column is simply not width enough for the data. If numeric data does not fit into the column width in `Excel`, then `Excel` shows `#####` in the cell.

Comment: Thanks @AxelRichter, i thought its some coding problem. apologize for my poor knowledge on excel. Its great help. i'm struggling from past 5 hours

Comment: "struggling from past 5 hours": [date cell showing as hash(#) excel](https://www.google.com/search?q=date+cell+showing+as+hash(%23)+excel) -> https://www.excelfunctions.net/cell-shows-hashes.html.